# Operating System Deadlock

Tags: operating-system, deadlock

I have a confusion in deadlock avoidance technique.
Could we achieve the deadlock avoidance by adding more number of resources?
a)Yes
b)No

Comment: (c) Yes and no. It depends entirely on what your actual question turns out to be, once the vagueness has been removed :-) What sort of resources are you talking about exactly? No amount of extra anything is going to fix two threads that try to lock common resources in a different order.

Answer (score 1):

Deadlock does not equal deadlock, you have to be more specific. For a "classical" deadlock as described in books (two processes trying to access both the screen and the printer at the same time) adding resources does not count as option, because the process needs *those specific* resources.

Of course, in this example, adding another printer would solve the deadlock. But to be extensible to software development, where a "resource" is something more abstract, like the access to a certain variable, adding resources is not considered a valid option. If two processes need to share access to a variable, it is not possible to introduce another without changing the behavior of the program.